# Can graphQL be set up as a callable function in Firebase (and how?)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, graphql, google-cloud-functions

Can graphQL be set up as a callable function in Firebase? All the examples in internet I was able to find set graphQL as `onRequest` HTTP function. Would it be possible to use the `onCall` function for graphQL? How to do it?

The reason I'd prefer to do it this way is authentication - callable functions offer the context object containing all relevant user data (or at least that's how I understand them), so you don't need to bother with handling the tokens.

Here's a simple template of a graphQL server inside an `onRequest` function using `express-graphql`:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require('express');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLID
} = require('graphql');

const app = express();

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
        tournament: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            args: {
                id: { type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) }
            },
            resolve(parentValue, args) {
                return 'Some result for id: ' + args.id
            }
        },
    }
})

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery
})

app.use(
    '/',
    graphqlHTTP({
        schema, 
        rootValue: root, // contents not relevant to the question
        graphiql: true,
    })
);

exports.graphql = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

- How to transform this template into `onCall` function?
- How to call the transformed function from the client using `httpsCallable()` method, so that the query/endpoint name and `args` are passed properly?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in a "simple" [HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) can be done in a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

Actually, Callable Cloud Functions are HTTP Cloud Functions with specific request and response formats, see the [Protocol specification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).

Comment: Well, then how exactly to wrap graphQL in a callable function?

Comment: "how exactly to wrap graphQL in a callable function" => You need to share some code, as this is quite a broad question. Did you try to adapt the  HTTP Cloud Function examples your mention in your question?

Comment: I'll expand my question in a moment then. But this is a question about a minimum template, not my specific code. I'll add the template GQL for onRequest function to my question.

Comment: I have expanded my question with the template code.